# mysql hebrew row displayed reversed

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, glassfish

I'm using glassfish with a webservice to access/write the mysql database.The problem is in mysql: when inserting english chars everything looks ok, but when inserting, say hebrew chars the rows are displayed reversed. Explainig the reversed thing: let's assume that table myTable has the following structure

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | ..
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | ...
| artist   | varchar(64)      | ...
| title    | varchar(64)      | ...
| genre    | varchar(128)     | ...
| filename | varchar(512)     | ...
| uploaded | tinyint(1)       | ...
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and this is how it look like for english and hebrew chars:
[image: MySQL hebrew row reversed]

I've set the charset and collate(although after creating and inserting data into DB):

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

And edited even the my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character-set-server = utf8
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Any help appreciated.